# Prevent measures from being influenced by date field in line chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table:

| DATE | FIRST CURRENCY | SECOND CURRENCY | EXCHANGE_RATE_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I am trying to plot a line chart showing how the index of second currency changes with time.
The base index should have a value of 100 and should start at the min date for the second currency in the table.

I have written the following formula to calculate the base exchange rate:

```
BaseExchangeRate = CALCULATE ( 
        AVERAGE ( 'Currency Table'[EXCHANGE_RATE_VALUE]), 
        FILTER('Currency Table', 'Currency Table'[DATE] = MIN('Currency Table'[DATE]))
)
```

and the values appear to be okay when displayed in a table.

[image]

However, when plotting this BaseExchangeRate to a line chart, instead of having 3 constant lines with values 687.95, 15.10, 605.37 for all time intervals, I am getting the actual value of the exchange rate for each period.

[image]

Ideally I need this value to be a constant for all range in time to be able to calculate the index for each time period. Grateful if anyone can advise how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to complete this through a work around.

First create one calculated column (index period) that will fetch the min date per First & Second currency

```
IndexPeriod = CALCULATE(MIN('Currency Table'[DATE].[Date]),FILTER('Currency Table','Currency Table'[SECOND_CURRENCY]=EARLIER('Currency Table'[SECOND_CURRENCY]) && 'Currency Table'[FIRST_CURRENCY]=EARLIER('Currency Table'[FIRST_CURRENCY]) ))
```

Then create another column that will fetch the value of the Exchange Rate Value per First & Second currency for specific index period

```
BaseRate = CALCULATE(MIN('Currency Table'[EXCHANGE_RATE_VALUE]),FILTER('Currency Table','Currency Table'[SECOND_CURRENCY]=EARLIER('Currency Table'[SECOND_CURRENCY]) && 'Currency Table'[FIRST_CURRENCY]=EARLIER('Currency Table'[FIRST_CURRENCY]) && 'Currency Table'[DATE].[Date]='Currency Table'[IndexPeriod].[Date]))
```